Unreal Engine 5 c++ get forcefeedback values
I am trying to implement a haptic feedback class in Unreal Engine 5.3 using the Windows Gaming API. I've attempted to incorporate as much functionality from the forcefeedback class as possible, but I'm encountering difficulty in retrieving values from the forcefeedbackeffects class using forceFeedback->getValues. The compiler is reporting a linker error. Can anyone provide guidance on how to successfully retrieving the force feedback values float(X, Y)? time and intensity.
The idea was to clone the function to be able to use it like the original forcefeedback function in blueprint just with the native impulse triggers support.
how to successfully retrieving the force feedback values float(X, Y) for time and intensity
